# Im trying my hardest to get a D3 Hierachy tree running. But failed at appending

Tags: d3.js, parent-child, hierarchy, appendchild, removechild

This is my first post - be gentle, I'm learning (or trying to) D3js.

I have been trying to put together a basic D3js Heirachy tree and have hit an issue.

While I have the basics pretty much covered I am hitting a wall.

I have started with this code as a foundation as its pretty close to what I'm trying to achieve.

http://blockbuilder.org/mattsrinc/16dab5a09aa46ed46975

However, as the original creator had stated - when you **ADD/APPEND** a new node it removes any and all children to the node you are using.

I've managed to isolate the point at which I think its occuring and replaced

Within the dndtree.js line 398.

***if (currentNode[0]._children!=null) {***

With

***if(!d.children==false ) {***

This stops the deletion and then I can add a node to the end and drag it into place - not ideal, but works.

I was wondering if any proper java wizards have a proper solution.

Any pointers appreciated and any help gratefully received.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Since your question is rather wide, I can't really try to fix or bring any code. If you are intersted, I've made a library which basically achieves what you are trying to do : https://github.com/PierreCapo/treeviz . Check the source code, it can lead you to the direction you want

Comment: Thats very kind I'll check it out straight away, thank you.

Comment: It maybe the version of Dreamweaver im using CS6 - but every instance of "nodeData" stops with error. However the treeviz playing works online and its almost what im looking for. If I could create a node and then rename it dynamically it would be perfect. On the link in my previous thread you can "right click" a node and it uses a popup dnd form that you can edit add and delete a node. If you Add a node it creates a random name, however if you then try and add another node to the parent you just used it simply overwrites ANY children attached..I've looked at D3.js libraries and Im stumped..